# Extract, modify and paste strings with user defined function

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a strings in data frame `'Media6xy-08', 'Medka21xy-22'` and I want to extract strings and numbers before or after certain characters and then finally output them as  a new column. And based on the digit values after `-` string if digits < 11 do some conditional work.

So, I attempted to write a function to this but could not figured out how to whole process.

```
import re
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A':['Media6xy-08',
                   'Medka21xy-22']})

df    

              A
0   Media6xy-08
1  Medka21xy-22
```

What want to have is

```
              A  modified_A
0   Media6xy-08  Med6x_8
1  Medka21xy-22  Med21y_22
```

I tried;

```
def modif(x):

   first_3_characters = x.str[0:3]

   digits_after_a_string = re.search(r"a(\d+)", x) # only want to get first two digits after sting 'a'

   digits_after_-_string = re.search(r"-(\d+)", x) # only want to get first two digits after string '-' exclude 0 if string is 08

   if digits_after_-_string < 11: # conditional 

      new_strings = first_3_characters + digits_after_a_string +'x'+ '_' + digits_after_-_string

   else:

     new_strings = first_3_characters + digits_after_a_string +'y'+ '_' + digits_after_-_string


   return new_strings


df['modified_A']=modif(df['A'])
```

But getting errors

> SyntaxError: can't assign to operator

again the expected output

```
              A  modified_A
0   Media6xy-08  Med6x_8
1  Medka21xy-22  Med21y_22
```

Comment: You just need one regex for that: ```digits=re.compile(r'(\d+)')```. Then you can use ```digits.findall('Medka21xy-22')``` for example and the result will be ```['21', '22']```.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this function with Python 3:

```
import re

digits=re.compile(r'(\d+)')

def modif(s):
   prefix = s[:3]
   numbers = [int(x) for x in digits.findall(s)]
   if numbers[1] < 11:
      return f'{prefix}{numbers[0]}x_{numbers[1]}'
   else:
      return f'{prefix}{numbers[0]}y_{numbers[1]}'
```

Or a more pythonic version:

```
import re

digits=re.compile(r'(\d+)')

def modif(s):
   prefix = s[:3]
   a,b = [int(x) for x in digits.findall(s)]
   return f'{prefix}{a}x_{b}' if b < 11 else f'{prefix}{a}y_{b}'
```

And here is a proof of concept:

```
Python 3.7.4 (default, Aug 12 2019, 14:45:07) 
[GCC 9.1.1 20190605 (Red Hat 9.1.1-2)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import re
>>> 
>>> digits=re.compile(r'(\d+)')
>>> 
>>> def modif(s):
...    prefix = s[:3]
...    numbers = [int(x) for x in digits.findall(s)]
...    if numbers[1] < 11:
...       return f'{prefix}{numbers[0]}x_{numbers[1]}'
...    else:
...       return f'{prefix}{numbers[0]}y_{numbers[1]}'
... 
>>> modif('Media6xy-08')
'Med6x_8'
>>> modif('Medka21xy-22')
'Med21y_22'
>>>
```

And here is how to apply it to your dataframe, adding a new column:

```
>>> df['Modified_A'] = [modif(x) for x in df['A']]
>>> df
              A  Modified_A
0   Media6xy-08     Med6x_8
1  Medka21xy-22   Med21y_22
>>>
```

Comment: thanks for your solution. However I'm getting error like this
`
  File "<ipython-input-164-40a3f785fe87>", line 6, in modif
    numbers = [int(x) for x in digits.findall(s)]

TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object `

Comment: Problem occurs when I apply `modif` to `modif(df['A'])`

Comment: The solution I posted is based on the example strings you gave us. You need to be sure all data is exactly in that format and be sure that they will have exactly two numbers embedded on them. If you can give a more complete sample of the data you are working on, I can help finding what is wrong.

Comment: I am using the example `df` that I provided the OP. it is giving an error when I do this `modif(df['A'])`. I'm not using any other data. just the example data that I provided here!

Comment: Oh! I see what's wrong so. The function expects just a string as parameter. You can't pass the entire dataframe to it. I guess pandas has a way to create another column by executing a function over every element of a column and that's the way you need to find out. I will take a look at pandas documentation to see what can be done.

Comment: yeah . it is always the case for me to apply functions to a dataframe:)

Comment: This will do the job: ```df['Modified_A'] = [modif(x) for x in df['A']]```.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an option.

```py
part1 = list()
part2 = list()
parts = df.A.str.split('-')
for p in parts:
    part1.append(p[0])
    part2.append(p[1])

def rep(num, cutoff=11):
    repstr = 'x' if (num<cutoff) else 'y'
    return repstr

df['Part1'] = part1
df['Part2'] = part2
df['Target'] = ['Med' + str(e1).replace('xy',rep(e2, 11)) + '-' + str(int(e2)) for e1, e2 in zip([''.join(re.findall('(\d*xy)', x)) for x in part1], part2)]
df
```

**Output**:

```
    A               Part1       Part2   Target
0   Media6xy-08     Media6xy    08      Med6x-8
1   Medka21xy-22    Medka21xy   22      Med21y-22
```